# Modifying bilinear interpolation matlab code to enlarge an image instead

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to modify this code to enlarge an image instead of shrinking it by when I change the
eliminate the factor line and made shrinking factor= 2 and multiply by s where s is used, I didn't get the right output. Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code:

```
    image=imread('b100.jpg');
    factor=1.5;
    shriking_factor= 1/factor;
    [r c d] = size(image);
    rn = floor(shriking_factor*r);
    cn = floor(shriking_factor*c);
    s = shriking_factor;
    im_zoom = zeros(rn,cn,d);
        for i = 1:rn;
            x1 = cast(floor(i/s),'uint16');
            x2 = cast(ceil(i/s),'uint32');
            if x1 == 0
               x1 = 1;
        end
        x = rem(i/s,1);
        for j = 1:cn;
            y1 = cast(floor(j/s),'uint32');
            y2 = cast(ceil(j/s),'uint16');
            if y1 == 0
                y1 = 1;
            end
            ctl = image(x1,y1);
            cbl = image(x2,y1);
            ctr = image(x1,y2);
            cbr = image(x2,y2);
            y = rem(j/s,1);
            tr = (ctr*y)+(ctl*(1-y));
            br = (cbr*y)+(cbl*(1-y));
            im_shrink(i,j) = (br*x)+(tr*(1-x));
        end
    end
    image_shrink = cast(im_shrink,'uint8');
    imshow(image_shrink)
```